# Can't construct a wstring from a wchar_t

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a struct called `LOGFONT` that I use from Windows headers

```
typedef struct tagLOGFONTW
{ LONG              lfHeight;
  LONG              lfWidth;
  LONG              lfEscapement;
  LONG              lfOrientation;
  LONG              lfWeight;
  BYTE              lfItalic;
  BYTE              lfUnderline;
  BYTE              lfStrikeOut;
  BYTE              lfCharSet;
  BYTE              lfOutPrecision;
  BYTE              lfClipPrecision;
  BYTE              lfQuality;
  BYTE              lfPitchAndFamily;
  WCHAR             lfFaceName[LF_FACESIZE];
} LOGFONTW, *PLOGFONTW, *LPLOGFONTW;

typedef __AW_ALIAS__(LOGFONT), *PLOGFONT, *LPLOGFONT;
```

I'm trying to construct a `std::wstring` from this structure's member `lfFaceName` like below,

```
std::wstring test(font.lfFaceName);
```

But, it fails to compile,

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<wchar_t>::basic_string(const CHAR [32])'
```

Comment: Your code is using a `WCHAR` not a `wchar_t`.  It appears to be mapping the `WCHAR` to `CHAR`.

Comment: Do you have `UNICODE` defined in your project? If not you're actually using the `LOGFONTA` structure.

Comment: Project template should have defined both `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` (yes, both are needed), as per [working with strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings).

Comment: The error message says you are trying to construct a `wstring` from a `CHAR[]` array, not a `WCHAR[]` array. That does not match the code you have shown, which makes me think you are actually using `LOGFONTA` instead of `LOGFONTW` (ie, using `LOGFONT` without `UNICODE` defined).

Comment: In the project properties the setting is under Advanced and is either "Use Unicode Character Set" or "Use Multi-Byte Character Set". Based on the error I'd say you have Multi-Byte selected.

Comment: I didn't have that one defined. Let me try to define it and see.

Comment: @RetiredNinja not multibyte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the following to my CMakeFile,

```
target_compile_definitions(TargetName PRIVATE -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE)
```

Comment: Or, you could simply change your code to use `LOGFONTW` directly, rather than using the `TCHAR`-based `LOGFONT`.